# Setting the best training / validation ratio in a Neural Network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, training-data

I am using a Neural Network to make a regression, using 10% of data to test.
But how can I set the best ratio values of training and validation datasets?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "best ratio", and actually you shouldn't be tuning the ratio at all. It should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the literature review papers.
Shortly, Hold-Out method has over estimation and K-fold cross validation usually has under estimation.
Hence, you can consider that your real result is approximately between answer of K-fold and Hold-out method.
Some people use another method like Bootstrap validation to have better assurance.